# Infinite Sample Space count ability

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let the sample space of an experiment be $S = \{0, 1, 2, \dots \}$, that is, a (countably) infinite sample space.
Define $A_k = \{k\}$ and $B_k = \{s \in S : s \geq k\}$ for $k \in S$. Suppose $P(A_k) = c4^k / {k!}$ for $k \in S$.

Determine the value of $c$. Compute $P(A_0)$ and $P(B_1)$.

Comment: Hello, I am not able to understand the question. Please help

Comment: @RushabhMehta  I am not able to determine P(B1)

Comment: @RushabhMehta, I have deduced P(Ao) = 1/e^4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

The sets $A_k=\{k\}$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots$ are disjoint and cover $S$ so that: $$1=P(S)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(A_k)$$
This enables you to find $c$.

Comment: I am sorry, I'm new to this topic, I am still not able to figure it out

Comment: Start with finding an expression for RHS in my answer.

Comment: Got it! Answer c=1/e. Am I correct? How do I find P(B1)?

Comment: How do I get P(B1)? P(Ao) = 1/e^4, am I correct?

Comment: Note that $A_0$ and $B_1$ are disjoint sets with $A_0\cup B_1=S$. That leads to  $P (A_0)+P(B_1)=P(S)=1$. Your calculation of $P(A_0)$ is correct.